# Buscar texto dentro de un div webdriver remotedriver selenium

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas noches, necesito saber como leer ese texto "`rock pesado`", utilizando `RemoteWebDriver` de Selenium. He intentado buscar el class pero no me lo encuentra.

```
$element3 = $web_driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::className('pull-left mua-security-question'));
```

Me da este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguno tiene una idea de que podria hacer?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El método que estás usando no permite multiples clases, así que tienes al menos dos opciones:

1. Validar que una de esas clases sea única en el elemento y hacer:

```
WebDriverBy::className('CLASEUNICA');
```

2. Cambiarlo por un selector CSS para darle soporte a obtener elementos con clases compuestas:

```
$element3 = $web_driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('.pull-left.mua-security-question'));
```

Ref: https://php-webdriver.github.io/php-webdriver/1.3.0/Facebook/WebDriver/WebDriverBy.html#method_className